Because sun_gold depends on flutter_woocommerce any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed?
Because sun_gold depends on flutter_woocommerce any which doesn't support null safety, version
solving failed.
Using these packages 4 years ago for website and its app using flutter wocommerce now error is
driver not found for that app and these is still error can we have another way to tackle this.
Its start working with flutter wocommerce of another thing

The WooComerce Library you're trying to use does not support null safety,because was created using dart 2,
so is incompatible with the current flutter/dart version
some options:

Look for another package with stable support or recent updates,eg: This one here
fork the WooComerce Library code and give it support,upgrade.


There is a driver error while loggin in.

loggin in??  where?
